# Name of current Notebook

Tags: files-and-directories

I've searched the documentation, this forum and with google, but I was not able to find how to ask *Mathematica* to give back the name of the current notebook file one is working on. Perhaps something with `EvaluationNotebook[]`, but that gives a `NotebookObject`. How is it possible to use this information to retain just the filename?

Comment: `AbsoluteOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowTitle]` ?

Comment: or if it is saved (is it?): `NotebookFileName[EvaluationNotebook[]]`

Comment: The notebook is indeed saved, that was precisely what I was searching for... Thanks, once again!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the notebook is **saved**, you can use:

```
NotebookFileName[EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

or simply (thanks to @rm -rf)

```
NotebookFileName[]
```

and if it's just the file's name you are after:

```
NotebookFileName[] // FileNameSplit // Last
```

Alternatively, even for **unsaved** notebooks, try:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {"NotebookFileName"}]
```